# In the Diablo Franchise, what distinction can we make between Magi, Sorcerers, and Wizards?

Tags: video-games, diablo

The Horadrim are composed of 'Magi', the classes from Diablo I & II are Sorcerers and the class from Diablo III calls themselves a Wizard (to distinguish themselves from the Sorcerers/Magi?).

Is there any nuance to these names we can infer from novels, cinematics or otherwise from the franchise?

<sub>Note: I don't consider material on wiki-pages to be canonical, unless it references an official text.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three can can be roughly split by their schooling or status within the mage-clans.

Magi can be applied as a generic term or, more properly, to one of the mage-clans of the East.

Sorcerors do not have that official affiliation, but share the magi's training and use magic in a similar way.  They can be thought of wandering magi.

Wizards are rogue magic users, born of their own talent rather than schooling within the mage-clans and their schools of magic.  They do not respect the same norms as the magi and sorcerors.

From the Diablo I manual:

> Although practitioners of the mystic arts are scarce within the often
>   superstitious and religious lands of the West, many magi have made the
>   pilgrimage from the Far East to see for themselves what horrors lie
>   beneath the ruined Cathedral of Khanduras. The veiled Brotherhood of
>   the Vizjerei, one of the eldest and most dominant mage-clans of the
>   East, has sent many of its acolytes to observe the dark events
>   unfolding in Khanduras first hand.
>
> The Vizjerei, known for their brightly colored turinash -or
>   spirit-robes have taken a keen interest in both gathering knowledge of
>   demons and seeing them slain. The Vizjerei elders hope that their
>   acolytes will learn the secrets of the dark evil that they sense
>   growing in the West and can destroy it. The possibility of discovering
>   long-lost tomes of magical knowledge within the confines of the
>   labyrinth has also captured the interest of many wandering Sorcerers.

From Blizzard's [class description of the Wizard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/) in Diablo III:

> Magic-users hail from academies throughout Sanctuary – from Xiansai to
>   Caldeum – bearing monikers like "sorcerer" and "mage," but those who
>   would refer to themselves with the derogatory epithet "wizard" are as
>   similar to their fellow spellcasters as a lion is to a kitten. Wizards
>   and sorcerers both wield the hidden mysteries of the arcane; there,
>   the commonalities end.
>
> Wizards are known for a number of qualities: not only rebelliousness
>   and flair, but also disdain for the endless lessons and prattling
>   about caution and safety that echo from academic schools of magic.
>   Wizards’ superior attitudes seem to stem from their natural talent –
>   their ability to wrestle the ambient force of magic into submission
>   and direct it to their ends by will and instinct. Any accidents that
>   might occur due to their lack of finesse are unfortunate…but that
>   rarely stops wizards from indulging in their unstable power.

Comment: This is interesting, because in my experience the description of Wizard and Sorcerer is normally reversed in other fiction.

Comment: @Pureferret: Yup.  And Blizzard knows it.

Comment: @Pureferret The "normal" distinction you describe was popularised by Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition. Before that, both words were used in all sorts of ways. It's amazing how influential a single source can be.